# How do I call 3rd party HTTP APIs inside twilio function?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to call my nodejs API inside Twilio function but it's not working. below is my code

```
var got = require('got');
var requestPayload = {foo: 'bar'};

got.post('https://your-api.com/endpoint', 
      { body: JSON.stringify(requestPayload), 
        headers: { 
        'accept': 'application/json' 
        }, 
       json: true
     }).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response.body)
     callback(null, response.body);
   }).catch(function(error) {
   callback(error)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `got` you can make post request like this:

```
    got.post('https://your-api.com/endpoint', { // pass your twilio api
        json:  JSON.stringify(requestPayload), // pass your request data as json 
        responseType: 'json'
    }).then(function(response) {
         console.log(response.data)
         callback(null, response.data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
         callback(error)
    });
```

Comment: you have to learn about got npm first https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

Comment: Thankyou so much.. i got it there was some problem with got package syntax.